# What are the differences in usage and meaning between 천천하다 and 느리다 meaning 'slow'?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

I was in the supermarket just now and the till was responding very slowly (i.e. there was a long wait for the prices to come up after the item was scanned).

I remarked, "천천하지", but that felt wrong to me - but a native Korean confirmed that 느리지 was more appropriate. But why is this? Is it because 느리다 is more appropriate for talking about a long *wait*, rather than literal motion? Or is it more appropriate for an exclamatory observation than 천천하다?

In general, what are the differences in usage and meaning between 천천하다 and 느리다?

Comment: there's no such word like 천천하다 in korean. We usually say 천천히.

Comment: @user1502 I know 천천히 is the most common form, but wouldn't 천천하다 still be the 'dictionary' form? E.g. http://alldic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kew000070835 or http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=37152501.

Comment: @topo morto : I am suprised at the word 천천하다, because I have never seen and heard that word. But I could check the word in internet dictionary.

Comment: @HKLee see my previous comment! :)

Comment: You're right, an adjective `천천하다` does exist. However, (I don't know why), its adverb form, `천천히` is much more common use of it; I'd say, overwhelmingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Take your time walking. Don't be too slow"

> "천천히 걸어. 너무 느리게 걷지 마."

#### Difference in Intent, Active/Passive Voice

Two sample phrases:

1. Pondering or deliberately thinking

> [**천천히** 생각하다](http://endic.naver.com/krenIdiom.nhn?sLn=en&idiomId=6dd7be54136546e3944037214df1ae59)

vs.

2. Time passes slowly

> [시간이 **느리게** 간다](http://endic.naver.com/example.nhn?sLn=en&exampleId=27306390&webCrawl=0&query=She%20was%20greatly%20impatient%20with%20the%20slow%20passage%20of%20time.)

From my experience, I find that 천천하다 tends to describe a deliberate/active decision which implies qualities of carefulness, prudence, or leisurely pacing. 느리다 is a basic description of speed on a spectrum.

#### Compare with Antonyms

- 천천하다 controlled pace vs. 서두르다 hurried/rushed
- 느리다 delayed, slow vs. 빠르다 instant, fast

#### General Connotation

- 천천하다 is often used in a positive tone while
- 느리다 is objective or conveyed negatively (where speed is expected or considered a quality).

Answer (score 1):

(a) son : 할머니가 ... 오래요. (Granmother says that you should come)

father : 너 왜 말이 **느려** ? 빨리 빨리 못해 ? (Why is yout talking slow ? Talk speedly)

mother : 속도는 중요하지 않아. **천천히** 정확하게 하는 것이 중요해. ( Speed is not important. Talking slowly and correctly is important)

(b) Usually, even though I want to do something fast, my body is not
followed. Here we use 느리다 : 나는 말이 느려요.

In other words, 느리다 is just observation : 거북이는 느리다. (Turtle is slow)

And when we have some intension, we use 천천히 :

(1) 지뢰를 밟지 않기 위해서 **천천히** 걸었다. (To avoid bomb, I walk slowly)

(2) 그는 내게 **천천히** 걸어 왔다. 그리고 내 지갑을 훔쳐갔다. (He walked to me slowly. And he stole my wallet.)